# Convert a list with tabbed numbers to a numeric array or matrix

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, split

I have a list that each element represents a string of message information:

```
rawdata = 
['1 1474585  1    19                                3', 
 '2 1474585  1    19                                2', 
 '3 1474585  1    27                                2', 
 '4 1474585  1    27                                2']
```

The information describes the following: [CAN MessageID DLC Data Time]
In order to access and analyze the information I am trying to split the list and turn it into a numeric array. I tried using split:

```
longstring = str.split(str(rawdata))
```

but that just divides the list to one long string:

```
longstring=
["['1", '1474585', '1', '19', "3',", "'
    2",  '1474585', '1', '19', "2',", "'
    3", '1474585', '1', '27', "2',
  "'4", '1474585', '1', '27', "2',",]"]
```

What I am trying to acheive is the option to call for all the messageID's by writing:

```
mydreamarray[:][0] = [1,2,3,4]
mydreamarray[:][1] = [1474585,1474585,1474585,1474585]
mydreamarray[:][2] = [1,1,1,1]
mydreamarray[:][3] = [19,19,27,27]
mydreamarray[:][-1] = [3,2,2,2]
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `numpy.array`

```
import numpy as np
newarray = np.array([[int(i) for i in j.split()] for j in rawdata])
```

Then for example

```
>>> newarray
array([[      1, 1474585,       1,      19,       3],
       [      2, 1474585,       1,      19,       2],
       [      3, 1474585,       1,      27,       2],
       [      4, 1474585,       1,      27,       2]])
>>> newarray[:,0]
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> newarray[:,1]
array([1474585, 1474585, 1474585, 1474585])
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `zip` with `list-comprehension`. `zip(*[..])` will transpose the data.

```
l = list(zip(*[map(int,i.split()) for i in rawdata]))
print (l)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2, 3, 4),
 (1474585, 1474585, 1474585, 1474585),
 (1, 1, 1, 1),
 (19, 19, 27, 27),
 (3, 2, 2, 2)]

l[1]
#(1474585, 1474585, 1474585, 1474585)
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Voted up.

Answer (score 0):

You really ought to work things like this out for yourself. That's how you learn. No pain, no gain. Asking other people to do your work for you won't teach you anything.

This may help

How do you set up an empty `mydreamarray`? Python arrays start at zero, so you can't have an element -1. However, you might use a dict. A dict can have any integer or string as a key. So,

```
mydreamdict={}
mydreamdict[-1] = []  # etc
```

Or it might be better to give up on using -1 and use 4 instead?

To append to a list, you use its `.append()` method

`rawdata` is a list of raw rows, and you want to do something with each of them, appending the data fields to the empty lists in `mydreamdict`. So

```
for row in rawdata:
    fields = split( row )
    mydreamdict[0].append( ... something out of fields  )
    #... more code needed
```

fields is a list of strings. You want to convert the string to an integer before you store it. The built-in `int()` function does that.

Comment: Of course there is an element -1; it's the last element in the list

Comment: Oh, of course ... but that's the same as the N-1th element, where N is the length of the array. While you are building or describing an array it doesn't usually make sense to refer to "last", and `[-1]` is a form of indexing rather than anything separate from `[N-1]`.

Comment: Thanks guys. The way I mainly work things out for myself is by reading posts in stackoverflow. I didn't find any answers to this question, so I asked (This is the first question I have ever asked after quite some time learning Python) Sometimes the questions asked seem trivial but it is a big help for the beginners. Thanks again